# Materializecss align several switches

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm using [materlizecss](http://materializecss.com). I want to create a form with several switches (on-off), the label of each one is different, so the switches are not aligned:
[image: Current state]

I want them to be aligned, so every "switch" is right aligned and the text is left aligned, something a bit like this:

[image: Material example]

Currently, my switches are almost a copy-paste from the materializecss web examples:

```
<div class="switch">
  <label>
    My Cool Label
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="lever"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried? This should be a very basic thing to do in CSS. Have you even tried to `float:right` the elements in question? Add the CSS that you have tried. Perhaps even make your code a snippet inside of the editor using `CTRL+M`

Comment: I'm working with materializecss, without custom css on this part for now, I would like not only a css hack, but a proper way of doing this along with the library

Comment: You response clearly shows your lack of understanding. Using CSS is **not** a "hack". Using CSS **IS** the **proper** way of doing this.

Comment: Trying css without knowing how the already existent css works, just to see how it fits **is** a hack, I would like to know how to use css properly for this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.container {
  padding:10px 0;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.lever {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
 <div class="switch">
  <label>
    My Cool Label
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="lever"></span>
  </label>
 </div>
</div>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="switch">
  <label>
    My Cool Label
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="lever"></span>
  </label>
 </div>
</div>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="switch">
  <label>
    My Cool Label
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="lever"></span>
  </label>
 </div>
</div>
```

Ignore the containers and it's CSS, it's there as a visual guide. There is only one CSS rule applied to the switch and it is **not** a "hack" as you call it.

Comment: Be sure to hit the big blue `run code snippet` button

Comment: I believe you @ProEvilz.

Comment: Thank you, and by the way, with hack I meant trying random stuff to see if it works by myself as you suggested in the first comment, not about the code. Thanks also for pointing the big blue button.